# Template Url in component not working while Angular 1.5 to Angular 6 migration

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm working on migrating a Angular 1.5 project to Angular 6. The templateUrl used in Angular 1.5 component is not working. I'm using following packages,

Angular cli 6.0.8
typescript 2.7.2
Angular 6.0.7

I have Angular 1.5 components which has templateUrl mapped. I successfully was able to build this hybrid app where my angular 1 and angular 6 components are getting rendered. Whenever I load the project the templateUrl gets the path as 404 not found, hence angularjs 1.5 component does not get rendered. While if I use 'template' with inline html strings then it works.

My Angular 1.5 code is in javascript while I'm using typescript for my Angular 6 code

Does anyone has some idea on this I'm struck in this issue for last couple of days

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
angular.
module('app.users').
component('userDetails', {
    templateUrl : './ng1/app/src/users/user-details.html',
    //template: 'This is user detail',
    controller: UserController
});
```

When using template it works fine. While templateUrl is not working. I have tried the following links
./ng1/app/src/users/user-details.html 
./app/src/users/user-details.html 
../user-details.html
./users/user-details.html

My component js file is present under ./ng1/app/src/users
but while build happens using gulp the bundle js gets created at root folder

**EDIT**

Error that I'm receiving is below,

zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:8082/ng1/app/src/users/user-details.html 404 (Not Found)

angular.js:13236 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ./ng1/app/src/users/user-details.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

**EDIT**
Browser url : http://localhost:8082/users

Route is  specified as

```
$routeProvider.when('/users', {
      template: '<user-details></user-details>'
    })
```

Comment: It looks like a path issue. You need to check 404 url against your folder structure.

Comment: How do you build the Angular 6 app? What is the templateUrl value?

Comment: @hurricane .. This path provided is correct as far as folder structure is concerned, it was working fine when angular 1.5 code is run independently. Is there something with cli ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: @kvetis I build it using angular cli. Template url used in angular 1.5 component is not working

Comment: @SagarWasule as i told you, you need to share with us 404 url and folder structure.

Comment: @hurricane updated my question with more details

Comment: @SagarWasule Hey Bro! Can you open chrome console and show us 404 url error?

Comment: @hurricane updated my question with more details

Comment: @SagarWasule Can you also show us the browser url when you are routing users page with `template`

Comment: @hurricane updated my question with more details

Comment: @SagarWasule Can you try `templateUrl : 'users/user-details.html'`

Comment: @hurricane This is not working got this error zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:8082/users/user-details.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I guess your templates are not getting served by the angular-cli. I don't know much about angular-cli server, but maybe it needs to be told to serve your static files. In NG6, the angular-cli automatically inlines ng6 templates for you, because they are required using webpack.

Comment: @SagarWasule Hi, Did you resolve this issue as i am also facing this issue during migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the file on the top

```
import '/ng1/app/src/users/user-details.html';
```

And in the component,

```
templateUrl: 'users.user-details.html';
```